# How to call a method from another class in c#?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

In C#, I have a class with a method like this:

```
namespace ControlCenter
{
    public partial class Canvas
    {
        ...
        public void display(string itemID)
        {
            ... // here assign some properties to the item
            this.Children.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

This function allows me to add an item to my canvas successfully. Now I want to call this method in another different class like this:

```
namespace ControlCenter
{
    public class addLayer
    {
        private ControlCenter.Canvas myCanvas = new ControlCenter.Canvas();

        public void add()
        {
            myCanvas.display("1234");
        }
    }
}
```

But this cannot add any item to my canvas. By debugging, I doubt the problem should be in this line:

```
this.Children.Add(item);
```

When calling `display` method from `addLayer` class, `this` is not pointing to the active canvas I guess. But I couldn't find any solution even after mass internet search. Any help?

Comment: item and itemID both are different??

Comment: how do you call the `addLayer` instance? (btw this sounds more like a method name than a class name)

Comment: Yes, itemID and item are different. "item" is of another class type named "DesignerItem", and itemID is a string.

Comment: I call addLayer again by creating: `ControlCenter.addLayer addlayer = new ControlCenter.addLayer;` Then `addLayer.add()` method is called.

Comment: `Children` is of type `UIElementCollection.Panel`.

Comment: You need a constructor in Canvas class that has InitializeComponent(). Once that is done, then calling the method should work for you.

Comment: `new` means it will create a *new* instance of the class, you need to look into how you can pass objects around instead of creating a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example shown I'm guessing canvas is a UserControl and your goal is that when you call the `add()` method you add an item to that usercontrol. But in the current example in the `addlayer` class you have created a brand new canvas which you have added an item to. The method does work its just you are adding the child to a brand new `canvas` which is not displayed. The way around this is to pass the displayed canvas instance to the `addlayer` class. after the InitialiseComponent() method.

Like so...

```
namespace ControlCenter
{
    public partial class Canvas : UserControl
    {

        public Canvas
        {
          InitialiseComponent();
          addLayer.myCanvas = this;

        }

        public void display(string itemID)
        {
            ... // here assign some properties to the item
            this.Children.Add(item);
        }
    }
}


namespace ControlCenter
{
    public static class addLayer
    {
        private static ControlCenter.Canvas myCanvas;

        public static void add()
        {
            myCanvas.display("1234");
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you  call addLayer.add() you will add an item to the displayed canvas

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now comes another problem: it cannot find "InitializeComponent()" method. My code is in ".cs" file, and various answers on the web say there should be a ".xaml" file and I should change "x:Class" to the namespace correctly. But I'm not having ".xaml" file to this class here. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I would say make your canvas class inherit from UserControl. Although I would say that there is already a `Canvas` Class [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas(v=vs.110).aspx) I guess it depends on what you are trying to do